# Is it possible to embedd PHP as a scripting language into a desktop application

Tags: php, scripting, programming-languages, interpreter

I know that my customers know PHP because i'm working on a PHP Tool (Running as a MFC Desktop Program)

Is it possible to embedd the PHP interpreter in a general purpose way like Python, Ruby, Lua or Javascript? And if yes - is it a hack or is there a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the state of the art requires some hacking.

You can compile php from source, passing --enable-embed=[shared|static] to `configure`.

Evidently, that's not all that simple, but the facebook folks have evidently tried to improve it, creating [phpembed](http://github.com/facebook/phpembed)

This [slide deck](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/10783691/Embedding-PHP) from back in 2006 seems to have some interesting tidbits on working with the library created via --enable-embed

Answer (score 1):

Can you rewrite the language using [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/)?  That's how I make Win32 PHP apps.

If you're running .NET, then you need to check out [Phlanager](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/TheChannel9Team/Phalanger-PHP-NET-compiler-revealed/), and then the answer is definitely yes.

Finally, there's various PHP compilers that can compile PHP code into DLLs that your apps can use natively.  see: http://phpcompiler.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Potentially yes](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/plphp/), although it is likely to be a hack.

Answer (score 0):

There's also embeddable PHP runtime [PH7](https://github.com/symisc/PH7) if you don't mind its GPL-like-or-commercial license.